# Run TFMA for Keras models without compiling

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, tensorflow-model-analysis

I am training a Keras model using custom training loops in TensorFlow, where the weights are updated using gradient tape rather than the `model.fit()` method. As such, the model is not compiled before training.

After exporting the saved_model, I am able to successfully load it for inference:

```py
model = tf.saved_model.load("path/to/saved_model")
pred_fn = model.signatures["serving_default"]
results = pred_fn(tf.constant(examples))
```

However, when I try loading it with TFMA using `run_model_analysis`:

```py
eval_shared_model = tfma.default_eval_shared_model("path/to/saved_model", eval_config=eval_config)
eval_results = tfma.run_model_analysis(
    eval_shared_model=eval_shared_model,
    data_location=test_tfrecords_path,
    file_format="tfrecords"
)
```

I get the following error:

```sh
WARNING:tensorflow:No training configuration found in save file, so the model was *not* compiled. Compile it manually.
-----------------------------------------------------
AttributeError      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-107-19f51f42014a> in <module>
      2     eval_shared_model=eval_shared_model,
      3     data_location=test_tfrecords_path,
----> 4     file_format="tfrecords"
      5 )

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_model_analysis/api/model_eval_lib.py in run_model_analysis(eval_shared_model, eval_config, data_location, file_format, output_path, extractors, evaluators, writers, pipeline_options, slice_spec, write_config, compute_confidence_intervals, min_slice_size, random_seed_for_testing, schema)
   1200             random_seed_for_testing=random_seed_for_testing,
   1201             tensor_adapter_config=tensor_adapter_config,
-> 1202             schema=schema))
   1203     # pylint: enable=no-value-for-parameter
   1204 

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pvalue.py in __or__(self, ptransform)
    138 
    139   def __or__(self, ptransform):
--> 140     return self.pipeline.apply(ptransform, self)
    141 
    142 

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py in apply(self, transform, pvalueish, label)
    575     if isinstance(transform, ptransform._NamedPTransform):
    576       return self.apply(
--> 577           transform.transform, pvalueish, label or transform.label)
    578 
    579     if not isinstance(transform, ptransform.PTransform):

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py in apply(self, transform, pvalueish, label)
    585       try:
    586         old_label, transform.label = transform.label, label
--> 587         return self.apply(transform, pvalueish)
    588       finally:
    589         transform.label = old_label

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py in apply(self, transform, pvalueish, label)
    628         transform.type_check_inputs(pvalueish)
    629 
--> 630       pvalueish_result = self.runner.apply(transform, pvalueish, self._options)
    631 
    632       if type_options is not None and type_options.pipeline_type_check:

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py in apply(self, transform, input, options)
    196       m = getattr(self, 'apply_%s' % cls.__name__, None)
    197       if m:
--> 198         return m(transform, input, options)
    199     raise NotImplementedError(
    200         'Execution of [%s] not implemented in runner %s.' % (transform, self))

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py in apply_PTransform(self, transform, input, options)
    226   def apply_PTransform(self, transform, input, options):
    227     # The base case of apply is to call the transform's expand.
--> 228     return transform.expand(input)
    229 
    230   def run_transform(self,

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py in expand(self, pcoll)
    921       # Might not be a function.
    922       pass
--> 923     return self._fn(pcoll, *args, **kwargs)
    924 
    925   def default_label(self):

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_model_analysis/api/model_eval_lib.py in ExtractEvaluateAndWriteResults(examples, eval_shared_model, eval_config, extractors, evaluators, writers, output_path, display_only_data_location, display_only_file_format, slice_spec, write_config, compute_confidence_intervals, min_slice_size, random_seed_for_testing, tensor_adapter_config, schema)
   1079       | 'ExtractAndEvaluate' >> ExtractAndEvaluate(
   1080           extractors=extractors, evaluators=evaluators)
-> 1081       | 'WriteResults' >> WriteResults(writers=writers))
   1082 
   1083   return beam.pvalue.PDone(examples.pipeline)

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pvalue.py in __or__(self, ptransform)
    138 
    139   def __or__(self, ptransform):
--> 140     return self.pipeline.apply(ptransform, self)
    141 
    142 

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py in apply(self, transform, pvalueish, label)
    575     if isinstance(transform, ptransform._NamedPTransform):
    576       return self.apply(
--> 577           transform.transform, pvalueish, label or transform.label)
    578 
    579     if not isinstance(transform, ptransform.PTransform):

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py in apply(self, transform, pvalueish, label)
    585       try:
    586         old_label, transform.label = transform.label, label
--> 587         return self.apply(transform, pvalueish)
    588       finally:
    589         transform.label = old_label

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py in apply(self, transform, pvalueish, label)
    628         transform.type_check_inputs(pvalueish)
    629 
--> 630       pvalueish_result = self.runner.apply(transform, pvalueish, self._options)
    631 
    632       if type_options is not None and type_options.pipeline_type_check:

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py in apply(self, transform, input, options)
    196       m = getattr(self, 'apply_%s' % cls.__name__, None)
    197       if m:
--> 198         return m(transform, input, options)
    199     raise NotImplementedError(
    200         'Execution of [%s] not implemented in runner %s.' % (transform, self))

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py in apply_PTransform(self, transform, input, options)
    226   def apply_PTransform(self, transform, input, options):
    227     # The base case of apply is to call the transform's expand.
--> 228     return transform.expand(input)
    229 
    230   def run_transform(self,

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py in expand(self, pcoll)
    921       # Might not be a function.
    922       pass
--> 923     return self._fn(pcoll, *args, **kwargs)
    924 
    925   def default_label(self):

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_model_analysis/api/model_eval_lib.py in ExtractAndEvaluate(extracts, extractors, evaluators)
    818     for v in evaluators:
    819       if v.run_after == x.stage_name:
--> 820         update(evaluation, extracts | v.stage_name >> v.ptransform)
    821   for v in evaluators:
    822     if v.run_after == extractor.LAST_EXTRACTOR_STAGE_NAME:

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pvalue.py in __or__(self, ptransform)
    138 
    139   def __or__(self, ptransform):
--> 140     return self.pipeline.apply(ptransform, self)
    141 
    142 

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py in apply(self, transform, pvalueish, label)
    575     if isinstance(transform, ptransform._NamedPTransform):
    576       return self.apply(
--> 577           transform.transform, pvalueish, label or transform.label)
    578 
    579     if not isinstance(transform, ptransform.PTransform):

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py in apply(self, transform, pvalueish, label)
    585       try:
    586         old_label, transform.label = transform.label, label
--> 587         return self.apply(transform, pvalueish)
    588       finally:
    589         transform.label = old_label

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py in apply(self, transform, pvalueish, label)
    628         transform.type_check_inputs(pvalueish)
    629 
--> 630       pvalueish_result = self.runner.apply(transform, pvalueish, self._options)
    631 
    632       if type_options is not None and type_options.pipeline_type_check:

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py in apply(self, transform, input, options)
    196       m = getattr(self, 'apply_%s' % cls.__name__, None)
    197       if m:
--> 198         return m(transform, input, options)
    199     raise NotImplementedError(
    200         'Execution of [%s] not implemented in runner %s.' % (transform, self))

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py in apply_PTransform(self, transform, input, options)
    226   def apply_PTransform(self, transform, input, options):
    227     # The base case of apply is to call the transform's expand.
--> 228     return transform.expand(input)
    229 
    230   def run_transform(self,

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py in expand(self, pcoll)
    921       # Might not be a function.
    922       pass
--> 923     return self._fn(pcoll, *args, **kwargs)
    924 
    925   def default_label(self):

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_model_analysis/evaluators/metrics_and_plots_evaluator_v2.py in _EvaluateMetricsAndPlots(extracts, eval_config, eval_shared_models, metrics_key, plots_key, validations_key, schema, random_seed_for_testing)
    757             plots_key=plots_key,
    758             schema=schema,
--> 759             random_seed_for_testing=random_seed_for_testing))
    760 
    761     for k, v in evaluation.items():

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pvalue.py in __or__(self, ptransform)
    138 
    139   def __or__(self, ptransform):
--> 140     return self.pipeline.apply(ptransform, self)
    141 
    142 

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py in apply(self, transform, pvalueish, label)
    575     if isinstance(transform, ptransform._NamedPTransform):
    576       return self.apply(
--> 577           transform.transform, pvalueish, label or transform.label)
    578 
    579     if not isinstance(transform, ptransform.PTransform):

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py in apply(self, transform, pvalueish, label)
    585       try:
    586         old_label, transform.label = transform.label, label
--> 587         return self.apply(transform, pvalueish)
    588       finally:
    589         transform.label = old_label

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py in apply(self, transform, pvalueish, label)
    628         transform.type_check_inputs(pvalueish)
    629 
--> 630       pvalueish_result = self.runner.apply(transform, pvalueish, self._options)
    631 
    632       if type_options is not None and type_options.pipeline_type_check:

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py in apply(self, transform, input, options)
    196       m = getattr(self, 'apply_%s' % cls.__name__, None)
    197       if m:
--> 198         return m(transform, input, options)
    199     raise NotImplementedError(
    200         'Execution of [%s] not implemented in runner %s.' % (transform, self))

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py in apply_PTransform(self, transform, input, options)
    226   def apply_PTransform(self, transform, input, options):
    227     # The base case of apply is to call the transform's expand.
--> 228     return transform.expand(input)
    229 
    230   def run_transform(self,

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py in expand(self, pcoll)
    921       # Might not be a function.
    922       pass
--> 923     return self._fn(pcoll, *args, **kwargs)
    924 
    925   def default_label(self):

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_model_analysis/evaluators/metrics_and_plots_evaluator_v2.py in _ComputeMetricsAndPlots(extracts, eval_config, metrics_specs, eval_shared_models, metrics_key, plots_key, schema, random_seed_for_testing)
    582       if eval_shared_model.model_type == constants.TF_KERAS:
    583         keras_specs = keras_util.metrics_specs_from_keras(
--> 584             model_name, eval_shared_model.model_loader)
    585         metrics_specs = keras_specs + metrics_specs[:]
    586         # TODO(mdreves): Add support for calling keras.evaluate().

~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_model_analysis/evaluators/keras_util.py in metrics_specs_from_keras(model_name, model_loader)
     60     # y_true, y_pred as inputs so it can't be calculated via standard inputs so
     61     # we remove it.
---> 62     metrics.extend(model.compiled_loss.metrics[1:])
     63     metrics.extend(model.compiled_metrics.metrics)
     64     metric_names = [m.name for m in metrics]

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'metrics'
```

I suspect this might be because I am not compiling the Keras model before exporting it. Does TFMA only support compiled models?

I am using `tensorflow==2.3.0` and `tensorflow-model-analysis==0.22.1`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your understanding is correct i.e., it is resulting in `error` because you are not `compiling` and consequently, not adding the `METRICS`.

It is evident from the statement specified in the [Tensorflow Model Analysis Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/model_analysis/get_started#model_types_supported) as well, which is mentioned below.

> Note: Only training time `metrics` added via **`model.compile`** (not
> `model.add_metric`) are currently supported for `keras`.